# How to access parent of nested json object

Tags: python, json, parent-child, parent, children

I have an arbitrary nested JSON object (parsed using json.load), consisting of dicts, lists, primitives etc. I traverse it depth first using recursion and tracking the path to the node in a linux fs format (for lists, I append /element to the path, so there can be multiple objects at a specific path), as following:

```
def traverse(node, path =''):
   if isinstance(node, dict):
      for key in node:
         traverse(node[key], path+'/'+key)
   elif isinstance(node, list):
      for elem in node:
         traverse(elem,path+'/element')
```

Each node may include a string which needs to be filled in using values of objects that can exist wherever in the tree, referenced in a relative path from the current node, eg: "{../../key} {./child1/child2/key}".
**Problem**: I can access the values of nodes that are children of the current node but I can't directly access the parent of the current node.
**Solutions I thought:** One solution I thought is to have a list of tuples (child,parent) and store the current node along with the child I'm about to recurse in, and then search that list in reverse when I need to go up. This is a bit dangerous because if the child is a primitive value then is will be equal to any other children of the same value and type and hence I may retrieve a wrong parent, but I think going through the list in reverse should take care of that right?
A different solution I thought is to have a dictionary with key being the child's path and value the parent node. I think this should work better because the only time paths clash is with list elements but they all have the same parent so it should be ok I think.

Are there any other suggestions? Or any comments on these two solutions?
Thank you

Comment: You don't. Python dictionaries, etc. have no reverse relation. You thus need to store it in a stack while traversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python the *vanilla* objects (well at least those used for JSON blobs like `list`, `dict`, etc.) have *no* relations to collections and objects that contain them.

That makes sense since basically a list can contain the *same* object multiple times. Furthermore an object can be stored both in a dictionary and a set at the same time. Unless you perform some sort of *garbage collection* algorithm (which is performance-wise very inefficient, and will "*scan*" over all objects), there is thus no trivial way to reconstruct a list of objects that refer to a given object. Even if we would scan the objects, it is still far from trivial to decide what we will see as the "*parent*", since there can be multiple parents.

In Python, a dictionary can even contain itself. Like:

```
# example of constructing a datastructure containing itself
some_dict = {}
some_dict['a'] = some_dict
```

Now we endlessly recurse on `some_dict`, for example `some_dict['a']['a']['a'] is some_dict`.

The point is that since your enumerate in a recursive way, you can maintain a *stack* that holds the ancestors. For example:

```
def traverse(node, path ='', stack=None):
    if stack is None:
        stack = [node]
    else:
        stack.push(self)
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key in node:
            traverse(node[key], path+'/'+key, stack)
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        for elem in node:
            traverse(elem,path+'/element', stack)
    stack.pop()
```

So each node pushes itself on the stack before we inspect the node, and at the end, it pops itself from the stack. We pass the stack recursively, so each recursive call can inspect the stack (not only the parent, but the entire trail up to the root).

Comment: Is the infinite recursion possible on a `json.load` result?

Comment: @CristiFati: no, since the JSON stream itself is finite, and it creates a new object. I'm only saying that once you constructed Python objects, the JSON context is gone: these are now *just* Python objects. We could have post-processed them creating infinite recursion, or simply passed an object we constructed to `traverse`. Furthermore if you create a custom deserializer, it is of course possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get back to the parent of a dict (or any recursive structure that doesn't have back-pointers) is to remember it as you traverse.

But notice that you're already doing this: your `path` string is a path from the top to the current node.

Let's write a function that uses the path:

```
def follow(head, path):
    if not path:
        return head
    first, _, rest = path.partition('/')
    return follow(head[first], rest)
```

Of course it would probably be nicer to build up `path` as a tuple of keys instead of a string, so we don't have to split them off (and so we don't have to worry about escaping or quoting if any of the keys might contain `/`, etc.); you can always `join` them at the end.

And it might be even better to build up `path` as a tuple of nodes (or key-node pairs) instead of just the keys, so we can access the parent in constant time as just `path[-1]` instead of in logarithmic time as `follow(head, path)`. But it really depends on what you're actually trying to do; your real code presumably doesn't just traverse the tree, building up paths to each node, and then doing nothing with them.

---

However, a really nice way to solve this would be to turn the traversal inside-out: make `traverse` an iterator:

```
def traverse(node, path =''):
   if isinstance(node, dict):
      for key in node:
         yield from traverse(node[key], path+'/'+key)
   elif isinstance(node, list):
      for elem in node:
         yield from traverse(elem,path+'/element')
   yield (node, path)
```

Now we can just loop over `traverse` to do anything we want as a post-order depth-first traversal:

```
for node, path in traverse(root):
    # do something
```

And now you can change it easily to yield `node, parent, path` (whether `parent` is the parent node, or the parent key, or whatever you wanted).

Comment: The path is not unique since all the elements of a list share the tag. I really liked the generator traversal though, I've moved it into my code! Thank you

Comment: @michaelg9 The usual way to solve the list problem is to include list indices in the path. There are different ways to do this (and I'd take a look at jsonpath, djson, kvc, and the other standard whose name I forget to see if I can just borrow one of them…), but the path to, say, `d['items'][1]['name']` can easily be `/items/1/name` or `/items[1]/name` or anything else that makes sense to you. Alternatively, of course, you can just pass a tuple of nodes down instead of a path string, and generate the path from that tuple when you need that, while using `pathnodes[-1]` when you need a parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a node by attribute value, and know what the node's parent nodes were, you can use the following:

```
def find_node_callback(node, stack, callback, path=''):
    stack.append(node)
    if callback(node,path,stack):
        return True

    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key in node:
            if find_node_callback(node[key],stack,callback,path+'/'+key):
                return True
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        for elem in node:
            if find_node_callback(elem,stack, callback,path+'/element'):
                return True

    stack.pop()
    return False
```

call it like so:

```
def isTargetNode(node,path,stack):
    if node == "value Im searching for":
        return True
    return False

# uses a callback to determine if the node is what you want
a = json.loads(jsonString) 
stack=[]          
if find_node_callback(a,stack,isTargetNode):
    # this array will contain all the parent items of your
    # target node, with the target node value being the last
    # thing stored in the array
    print(stack)
```